# Create a numbering system that depends on current Year

Tags: excel, vba

My spreadsheet is used to manage tasks. I add new tasks by running a small macro, and currently the numbering is simply 1, 2, 3, 4..., generated by the following code:

```
Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows(9).Row, 1).Value = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows(10).Row, 1).Value + 1
```

I would like, using `VBA`, to evolve this by adding a prefix to the number that represents the Year the task was initiated. Furthermore, the numbering should re-start at 1 for the first entry of each year. I.e

```
15-1, 15-2, 15-3, 15-4....16-1, 16-2, 16-3...
```

Any ideas for a simple code that could achieve this?

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it sorted out with Siddharth Rout's code :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic example. Amend it to suit your needs. You can also create a procedure and pass the row number to which you want the auto numbering to happen as shown at the end of this post.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim prev As Range
    Dim rw As Long

    rw = 9 '<~~ Change this to the relevant row
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rw, 1)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set prev = rng.Offset(-1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Check if there is one row above
    If Not prev Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Match the year
        If Left(rng.Offset(-1), 2) <> Format(Date, "yy") Then
            '~~> Restart numbering
            rng.Value = Format(Date, "yy") & "-" & 1
        Else
            '~~> Increment numbering. Split will extract the number
            rng.Value = Format(Date, "yy") & "-" & Val(Split(rng.Value, "-")(1)) + 1
        End If
    Else
        '~~> Restart numbering
        rng.Value = Format(Date, "yy") & "-" & 1
    End If
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Edit:**

Using it as a procedure where you can pass arguments.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Long
    r = 9 '<~~ Chnage this to the relevant row

    AllocateID r
End Sub

Sub AllocateID(rw As Long)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim prev As Range

    Set rng = Cells(rw, 1)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set prev = rng.Offset(-1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Check if there is one row above
    If Not prev Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Match the year
        If Left(rng.Offset(-1), 2) <> Format(Date, "yy") Then
            '~~> Restart numbering
            rng.Value = Format(Date, "yy") & "-" & 1
        Else
            '~~> Increment numbering. Split will extract the number
            rng.Value = Format(Date, "yy") & "-" & Val(Split(rng.Value, "-")(1)) + 1
        End If
    Else
        '~~> Restart numbering
        rng.Value = Format(Date, "yy") & "-" & 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

sure just do that:

```
Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows(9).Row, 1).Value = format(date,"yy") & "-" & _
Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows(10).Row, 1).Value + 1
```

Comment: `The numbering should re-start at 1 for the first entry of each year.` ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim startYear As Integer

priorYear = 2014

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To 100
        .Cells(i, 1) = CStr(priorYear + WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(i / 12, 0) & "-" & ((i + 1) Mod 12))
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```